# Problems creating new mesh- not showing up/invisible?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So when I try to add a sphere, it doesn't work properly; instead of a sphere, nothing shows up except the point with the circle around it as you can see to the right of the model I'm working on.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.  Does anyone have any ideas? I'm using cycles.

[image]

Comment: I think it is adding a sphere, its just so BIG that its bigger than your scene. You need to scale it down. Also your model seems very small, you may want to scale your model up some. OR it may be the exact opposite (hard to tell) Your model may be so big it makes the sphere so small you cant see it. One or the other.

Comment: That was it! Thanks haha I just recently started working using the metric system rather than the default so I guess I'm just not used to it! Thanks so much, that was easy.